# How to replace all numbers and "." by "" of a column in Dataframes spark scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

How to replace all numbers and "." i.e All decimal numbers should be replaced by "") of a column in Dataframes spark scala

Eg:`+56.5` or `-64.83` should get replaced by empty character which is ""

I am following

```
regexp_replace(col("col1"),"\\+|\\-|\\.|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9", "")
```

Is there any other better way of doing this

Thanks

Comment: Do you want all numbers to be replaced by empty string? Or only decimal numbers?
I.e. does +24 need to be replaced by "" or does it stay +24 ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like regexp for decimal numbers is required, tag "regex" can be added to question. 
Such regexp can be used:

```
// this is pattern to use
val decimalNumbersPattern = "[-+]?[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+"

val df = Seq("Replaced: +56.5", "Replaced: -64.83", "Remains: 44").toDF()
df
  .select(regexp_replace($"value", decimalNumbersPattern, "").alias("result"))
```

Output:

```
+-----------+
|result     |
+-----------+
|Replaced:  |
|Replaced:  |
|Remains: 44|
+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = meta.core.DataCore.spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (0, "+56.5"),
  (1, "-64.83"),
  (2, "+12.1234"),
  (3, "13"),
  (4, "-10.0"),
  (5, "2"),
  (6, "0")
)).toDF("id", "all_digitals")

df
  .withColumn("not_decimals", when(col("all_digitals").contains("."), "").otherwise(col("all_digitals")))
  .show()
```

Result is :

```
+---+------------+------------+
| id|all_digitals|not_decimals|
+---+------------+------------+
|  0|       +56.5|            |
|  1|      -64.83|            |
|  2|    +12.1234|            |
|  3|          13|          13|
|  4|       -10.0|            |
|  5|           2|           2|
|  6|           0|           0|
+---+------------+------------+
```